# How to update the whole view after deleting a photo in UIPageViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uipageviewcontroller

In my Album App, I display thumbnails of photos in a collection view and view every photo in a page view. Now I add a delete button in the page view, and after pressing the delete button, I can successfully delete the current photo in database. But I have trouble updating the current view. I want to know where could I add the updating code for current view(the view inserted in the page view) and more importantly, how to update current view like I firstly enter it from the collection view.

Here is my simple delete code.(self.ppvc is the photo page view controller where I display the current photo)

```
- (IBAction)deletePhoto:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender
{

    NSIndexPath *indexPathOfCurrentPhoto = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:self.photoNumber inSection:0];
    NSArray *photoToBeDeleted = @[indexPathOfCurrentPhoto];

    //delete from database
    [Photo deletePhotosFromAlbum:self.albumName withIndexPathArray:photoToBeDeleted inManagedObjectContext:self.ppvc.context];

    //delete from UI
    [self.ppvc.thumbnails removeObjectAtIndex:self.photoNumber];

}
```

Comment: You are not describing this very well. You have a collection view with thumbnails, and if the user clicks on one you switch to a separate display that uses a UIPageViewController to show one image/page with side-scrolling or page curl between pages? You need to describe your UI better, and also describe the action the user takes to delete a photo. Does the user tap a button to delete the current photo while viewing that photo in your page view controller, or while in the collection view?

Answer (score 0):

If you're displaying the thumbnails in a UICollectionview you're probably looking for the method [collectionView deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:].  For example

```
[self.collectionView deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:indexPathOfCurrentPhoto];
```

Alternatively you could choose to reload the section by calling the reloadSections method.

Comment: Sorry. You misunderstood my description. What I want to do is to update UI in page view. In my collection view, everything works well.

Answer (score 0):

I **THINK** you are saying that you want to have a delete button on the current page in the `UIPageViewController`, and that clicking the delete button should delete the current image, then update the page view controller to display the next image in line (somewhat like tearing a page out of a book, exposing the page underneath.)

If that's true then I think you want to use the `UIPageViewController` method `setViewControllers:direction:animated:completion:`. If I read the docs correctly, that method lets you replace the array of view controllers with a different array of view controllers. If you set animated: YES, it should animate scrolling/page curling to expose the page for the new current image.

**Disclaimer**: I've never tried to edit a list of pages from inside a `UIPageViewController' user interface before.